# Given the coordinates of an object in an image, is it possible to predict the coordinates of the same object in a different perspective?

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning, convolutional-neural-networks, reference-request

I am trying to figure out how to approach this.

Given training data of images and the pixel coordinates of the centre of an object in that image, would it be possible to predict the pixel coordinates of the object in the same "scene" in a different perspective, but with the object removed?

Comment: When you say "perspective", do you mean the same scene but viewing it from a different viewpoint/angle?